# is there a better solution to make sql result to one line?

Tags: mysql, sql

now i have a table `test_table` with some data like this:
(id-type is a unique index)

| id | type | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | a |
| 1 | y | b |
| 2 | x | aa |

and with the sql:

```
SELECT id,
       group_concat(IF(type = 'x', value, NULL) SEPARATOR '') AS 'x',
       group_concat(IF(type = 'y', value, NULL) SEPARATOR '') AS 'y'
FROM test_table
GROUP BY id;
```

i get the result like this:

| id | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b |
| 2 | aa | null |

it makes the 'type' to be a colume.
so this is a better way to get the same result?

a better sql to implements my question~

Comment: Yours is perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'x' THEN value END) AS x,
    MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'y' THEN value END) AS y
FROM test_table
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```